# Snowflake GMT String to Date Conversion

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We receive a string '2019-11-30T18:00:00GMT-06:00' in the JSON file and this need to be converted to timestamp to load into the timestamp column in the snowflake. I tried multiple options convert_timezone,to_timestamp etc, however in vain, Can you please let me know how i represent this string (2019-11-30T18:00:00GMT-06:00) in data format for comversion.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging a more Snowflake way to do this, you'd want to run something like this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-30T18:00:00GMT-06:00','YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SSGMT-TZH:TZM');
```

The output of this will be the date/time of your account default along with the timezone offset that goes along with that.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks @Mike , can you please share if any link where i can more info on this.Appreciate the help !!

Comment: @gopinathkolanchi This is the core link: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html, but I also find that this page is important to find the specific notations of each element: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions

Comment: Thanks ton @Mike :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below mentioned approach

if your table is create as below

CREATE TABLE TIMESTAMP_TEST(DATE TIMESTAMP);

Insert the value as

INSERT INTO TIMESTAMP_TEST SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('2019-11-30T18:00:00GMT-06:00','GMT'),'T',' ') FROM DUAL

Thanks

Comment: No need to use REPLACE statements.  You can just map the format of the string directly in the `TO_TIMESTAMP` or `TO_DATE` functions.